# Does FileZilla Open as many connections as the number of intended file transfers

Tags: sftp, filezilla

I read on this blog that FileZilla opens up a Primary connection for Navigation as well as Fallback and a Secondary Connection for File Transfers. What I am trying to understand is that whether File Zilla opens up 10 connections for 10 parallel upload of files OR one single secondary connection is re-used for transferring all  the ten files.

https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=4180

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just looked it up using TCPView from Sysinternals against N connections. Varying N from 1 to 5 and back. The connection numbers followed the configuration setting for "Max simultaneous transfers" when "Limit for concurrent downloads" and "Limit for concurrent uploads" is set to Zero.

So, short answer:

- FileZilla opens and retains a separate connection for browsing and
  navigation
- FileZilla opens one separate connection for a file
  transfer as described above.